# MongoDB connection error(the uri parameter)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i faced with next error:

**

**MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "object". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.**

**
Please help me fix it, maybe problem in //config.// before MONGO_URL ? What i have to do?

**My app code(app.js):**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const staticAsset = require('static-asset');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const config = require('./config');
const routes = require('./routes');
// database
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', config.IS_PRODUCTION);
mongoose.connection
  .on('error', error => console.log(error))
  .on('close', () => console.log('Database connection closed.'))
  .once('open', () => {
    const info = mongoose.connections[0];
    console.log(`Connected to ${info.host}:${info.port}/${info.name}`);
    // require('./mocks')();
  });
mongoose.connect(
  (config.MONGO_URL,
  { useMongoClient: true }
));

// express
const app = express();

// sessions
app.use(
  session({
    secret: config.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
    })
  })
);

// sets and uses
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(staticAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, config.DESTINATION)));
app.use(
  '/javascripts',
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'jquery', 'dist'))
);

// routes
app.use('/', routes.archive);
app.use('/api/auth', routes.auth);
app.use('/post', routes.post);
app.use('/comment', routes.comment);
app.use('/upload', routes.upload);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: error.message,
    error: !config.IS_PRODUCTION ? error : {}
  });
});

app.listen(config.PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${config.PORT}!`)
);
```

**config.js:**

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');

const root = path.join.bind(this, __dirname);
dotenv.config({ path: root('.env') });

module.exports = {
  PORT: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  MONGO_URL: process.env.MONGO_URL,
  SESSION_SECRET: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  IS_PRODUCTION: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  PER_PAGE: process.env.PER_PAGE,
  DESTINATION: 'uploads'
};
```

My project so big. I can show my files in answers.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require('dotenv').config()
const path = require('path');

const root = path.join.bind(this, __dirname);

module.exports = {
  PORT: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  MONGO_URL: process.env.MONGO_URL,
  SESSION_SECRET: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  IS_PRODUCTION: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  PER_PAGE: process.env.PER_PAGE,
  DESTINATION: 'uploads'
};
```

Comment: i got a new error : throw new Error('MONGO_URL is not present in config');

Comment: That means config.MONGO_URL is undefined. Can you please show your config file

Comment: Yes sure, the code is above in the post itself(config.js)

Comment: I observed that i had a mistake in my config.js after editting code , now i have a right config.js. i started my app.js again and got this message: "mongo url not found"

Comment: `console.log(config.MONGO_URL)` try this in app.js and see what it logs.

Comment: i got: "undefined". Full message:                                                                         "undefined" "mongo url not found"

Comment: ok.. `console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL)` try this code in config.js and see what it logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218140/discussion-between-rubybeginner-and-nithin-k-joy).

Comment: Problem was with .env file, Thank you Nithin K.J

Answer (score 0):

Pass these key value pairs :

```
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
);
```

Comment: i got a new error : throw new Error('MONGO_URL is not present in config');

Comment: Use the environment variable MONGO_URL. Something like:

export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/your_db

Comment: I observed that i had a mistake in my config.js after editting code , now i have a right config.js. i started my app.js again and got this message: "mongo url not found"

Comment: Show me your MONGO_URL string.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `mongoose.connect` line to this:

```js
mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Also it would be preferable to add some check if MONGO_URL is present:

```js
if (!config.MONGO_URL) {
    throw new Error('MONGO_URL is not present in config');
}

mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Comment: i got a new error : throw new Error('MONGO_URL is not present in config');

Comment: this means that MONGO_URL is not in your config.

Comment: I observed that i had a mistake in my config.js after editting code , now i have a right config.js. i started my app.js again and got this message: "mongo url not found"

Answer (score 0):

**In my case I have used it like this:**

```
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/todolists";
//connection
var connectionOptions = {
    auth: {
      user: "himanshubhardwaj",
      password: "himanshu@123"
          },
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    }
 mongo.MongoClient.connect(url,connectionOptions,(err,client)=>{
  if(err){
    console.log("Username/Password not matched at Mongo's side");
    return;
     }
 console.log("connected successfully to mongodb");
 var todolists=client.db('todolists');
```